# Populate collection using ref failed in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to populate credit collection into user collection, here's my credit schema

```
const CreditSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  credit: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  log: [String]
})
```

And my User Schema like so

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  credit: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Credit' } //I suspect something is not right here
})
```

Why I can't see credit in user's object below?

```
const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.query.id})
.populate('credit')
.exec()

console.log(user) // credit field is not present?
```

Comment: how are you saving the doc ?

Comment: Do you have credit field saved inside mongoDB ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey it's there, the userId of credit matched the user's id.

Comment: @FarhanTahir yes I do.